# Clean OS X Lion reinstall --  OK to not migrate ~/Library?

Tags: macos, osx-lion

Due to the issues I've been having with [Lion Server](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OS_X_Server#Mac_OS_X_10.7_.28Lion.29), I'm looking at a full re-install. I've got backups ([Time Machine](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_Machine_%28Mac_OS%29) + [CrashPlan](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CrashPlan), etc.), so I'm not super worried about the reinstall.

I'd kind of like to not restore `~/Library` when I restore my home directory. What do I have to be aware of when doing this? I know I'll lose application prefrences, is there anything else that I should be especially wary of?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You lose pretty much *everything* that isn't stored in some data file (document, image, movie) elsewhere. A *very incomplete* list of what is in `~/Library`:

- Application preferences
- Software license registrations
- Printer, screen, and other per-user system configuration
- Scripts for the AppleScript menu
- Saved Searches for Spotlight
- custom Services (e.g. created using Automator)
- Mail plugins
- All cached Mail data, and account information, filters, etc.
- Safari bookmarks
- Safari history
- custom Color Picker plugins
- third party application data, e.g. Firefox profiles, Thunderbird profiles, Things task lists, etc.
- Dashboard widgets you installed
- Fonts you installed
- Third party context menu plugins
- All iCal and address book data
- Saved passwords in all applications, other keychain items
- Dock, Launchpad, Mission Control configuration
- configuration which programs launch on login

Notably missing from this list is everything related to Unix/command line applications like your shell, that's stored in dotfiles right in your home directory. It depends on how you restore that whether those'll be lost as well.

---

For all intents and purposes, you'll have a fresh user profile with (maybe) applications and saved documents moved other.

Comment: great.  Thanks for the validation.  :)   I'm pretty much ok with losing everything on that list.  I've got my software lics in 1password, my dotfiles are in dropbox, and email/calendar etc. is in the browser.